# Push/Export large datframe from R to Vertica database

Tags: r, database, bulkinsert, dbi, vertica

I have a dataframe of 10M rows which needs to be uploaded back from R to Vertica Database.

The `DBwrite()` function from DBI is running into memory issues and I have tried increasing memory to 16g by

```
options(java.parameters = c("-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-Xmx16g"))
```

Still the process is running into memory issue. I am planning to use bulk copy option of vertica to copy the csv file to create the table.

1. I have created an empty table on vertica
2. When I am executing the query

```
dbSendQuery(vertica, "COPY hpcom_usr.VM_test FROM LOCAL \'/opt/mount1/musoumit/MarketBasketAnalysis/Code/test.csv\'  enclosed by \'\"\' DELIMITER \',\' direct REJECTED DATA \'./code/temp/rejected.txt\' EXCEPTIONS \'./code/temp/exceptions.txt\'")
```

I am running into this error.

> Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set",  :
> Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
> JDBC ERROR: [Vertica]JDBC A ResultSet was expected but not generated from query "COPY hpcom_usr.VM_test FROM LOCAL '/opt/mount1/musoumit/MarketBasketAnalysis/Code/test.csv'  enclosed by '"' DELIMITER ',' direct REJECTED DATA './code/temp/rejected.txt' EXCEPTIONS './code/temp/exceptions.txt'". Query not executed.

Please help with what i'm doing wrong here.
Vertica also provides STDIN option aswell. [Link](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPYExamples.htm)

Please help me how can I execute this.

My Environment.

CENT OS 7
R 3.6.3  (No R Studio here I have to execute this from CLI)
Tidyverse 1.0.x
Vertica driver 9.x
System 128GB Memory and 28Core system.

Comment: I don't think "copy from local" is an sql query. It looks a lot more like a command to be used with their specific driver software.

Comment: I generally use it in my client side like DBeaver and it works. so finding a way for the query to point to the file within R. Alternatively there is s STDIN approach which i am not able to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dbSendUpdate(vertica, "COPY hpcom_usr.VM_test FROM LOCAL \'/opt/mount1/musoumit/MarketBasketAnalysis/Code/test.csv\'  enclosed by \'\"\' DELIMITER \',\' direct REJECTED DATA \'./code/temp/rejected.txt\' EXCEPTIONS \'./code/temp/exceptions.txt\'")
```

instead of dbSendQuery did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you fire `dbSendQuery()` , which lives with a following `dbFetch()` and a final `dbClearResult()` - but only for query SQL statements - those that actually return a result set.

Vertica's `COPY <table> FROM [LOCAL] 'file.ext' ...` command is treated like a DML command. And for those - as this docu says ...

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbSendQuery

.. you need to use `dbSendStatement()` for data manipulation statements.

Have a go at it that way - good luck  ...